# Flash streaming video hosting solutions

Tags: flash, video, streaming, hosting

I'm trying to find a reliable yet cost-effective solution for hosting our small collection of .f4v videos. We're a small company so price is a major consideration. We also need the video to stream.

I found Vimeo and it's cheap but they don't provide streaming.

Viddler looks like a good solution. It's is a little more expensive but streaming is available.

We're trying to avoid enterprise solutions such as Akamai, etc.

Any others out there?

I also know about Red5 but prefer to have it hosted.

Thanks.

Comment: i have used Akamai  But don't know about pricing. Their customer support was pretty good though.

Comment: We ended up hosted the videos ourselves with HTTP Dynamic Streaming (http://www.adobe.com/products/httpdynamicstreaming) on Apache with the OSMF player (http://www.osmf.org/developers.html). It's completely free and almost as good as "real" streaming.

Answer (score 1):

use Amazon S3 for storage and Cloudfront for delivery/streaming...relatively cheap and easy to setup

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2009/12/15/announcing-cloudfront-streaming/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [CloudFiles by Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/) to host FLVs before and it's *very* easy to set up and *very* easy to execute. I'm not sure about cost efficiency to Cloudfront, though.

Comment: It looks like they host normal content files like flvs but I don't see a video streaming solution. Our videos are upward of 20 minutes (almost eternity in internet time) and we want our users to be able to skip ahead without having to wait for the video to load.